# How do I docker-compose up without blocking ci and guessing duration

Tags: docker

Currently in Travis-CI I have to run docker-compose with `-d` so that it doesn't block the build process.  Unfortunately this means I need some way of making sure my containers are operational before proceeding with tests.  The best way I've found to do that is to use `sleep`.

Aside from using Docker's CI (which stinks IMO), does anyone have any recommendations on how to accomplish this?

Currently I use:

```
  - docker-compose up -d
  - sleep 6
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something simple:

```
- docker-compose up -d
- while true; do echo Checking...; echo $(docker-compose exec service_name test-command something) | grep -q some-output && break; sleep 0.5; done ;
```

Or better call a script that do this better formatted (you need to create a */health-check.sh*):

```
- docker-compose up -d
- while true; do echo Checking...; (docker-compose exec service_name /health-check.sh) && break; sleep 0.5; done ;
```

*/health_check.sh*:

```
#!/bin/bash

curl http://localhost:PORT && exit 0
exit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`docker-compose ps` shows the status of the containers, which should be Up if everything went ok.